# how to upgrade unlocked iphone 4s to iOS 7.0.4

Tags: iphone

How to upgrade my iphone 4s currently running on iOS 5.0 to iOS 7.0.4? I would want to get step by step instructions.

Comment: Is your phone unlocked or jailbroken?

Answer (score 1):

How about using google or the official [Apple support](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4623?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US)?